# Ghost indices in pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz'],
           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=index)

first  second
bar    one       1.791849
       two       0.334121
baz    one      -0.655277
       two      -1.296491
```

Now I filter on the index and remove "one":

```
t = s[s.index.get_level_values(1) != "one"]

first  second
bar    two       0.334121
baz    two      -1.296491
```

The strange thing is that "one" still shows up in the index (dependent on the method I use to access index values):

```
t.index.levels[1]

Index(['one', 'two'], dtype='object', name='second')
```

Or:

```
t.index.get_level_values(1)

Index(['two', 'two'], dtype='object', name='second')
```

Would you have any idea why "one" is still showing in the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html), because by default after filtering is index not changed, I guess reason is performance:

```
print (t.index.remove_unused_levels())
MultiIndex([('bar', 'two'),
            ('baz', 'two')],
           names=['first', 'second'])

print (t.index.remove_unused_levels().levels[1])
Index(['two'], dtype='object', name='second')
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. I assume this implies that pandas implicitly saves a set of indices that it has seen for a `df`? Can you maybe elaborate?

Comment: @Carsten - I was first not [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3686), then [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2770#issuecomment-29551251) and this function was created for solve this problem.